# What you wish to remove or add to linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, user-experience

I was wondering what or how we can do to develop a better Linux kernel or variant (if necessary).

What problems does Linux have and how could they be solved or if Linux needs some feature?

**Justification:**
Due to the system of usefulness of response, the great community that is here and the interest that can have in this response both to a passionate newcomer and to an expert.
I think it is a question that could strongly favor the community, its development and the future of Linux development and variants.

Comment: … but does not fit a Q&A WWW site where answers are marked by people for being right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- Pick a Topic of interest
- Subscribe to the corresponding mailinglist @ http://vger.kernel.org/vger-lists.html
- Listen for a while
- Contribute
- Submit

That's about it.